# CSS rotation on SVG tag

Tags: css, svg, transform, css-transforms

**Update**

After checking how other programs draw rotated lines (the same way as mine), I see that it goes back to screen resolution.

**Original question**

I have an `SVG` with a `line` in it. If I rotate the whole `SVG` element (i.e. the `SVG` tag), the `line` is rendered with ugly edges (checked in FF30 and Chrome35).
Is it some bug, or did I miss something? Is it a bad idea to apply `CSS3 transform` on an `SVG` tag?

To make my question specific:
**How can we apply CSS rotation on an SVG element such that the elements in it get rendered nicely?**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5P9yz/

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/amGY9l.png

**HTML**

```
<svg height="8" width="100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

     <line x1="0" y1="4" x2="100" y2="4"
           stroke="red" stroke-width="8" />
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(.125rad);
       -moz-transform: rotate(.125rad);
         -o-transform: rotate(.125rad);
            transform: rotate(.125rad);
}
```

Comment: The screenshot is pretty much what I would expect. What would you expect? It doesn't look jagged to me. If you tried it with shape-rendering="crispEdges" you'd see **real** jagged edges.

Comment: I would expect the line to have sharp edges, as much as the screen resolution makes it possible. Now that I checked how other programs draw their lines (the same way as in my example), I see that this is the best the screen resolution allows for. Thank you for your comments.